# How to remove one command completion from zsh?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have a local script called `bpython`, and my zsh won't complete any pathnames after that. I can see that there is a `_bpython` completion script in my `$_comps` which I assume is built-in. How can I remove that or override it to treat it as a generic command?
I'm not using oh-my-zsh or any fancy plugins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove it from `_comps`. That's where the completion system finds how to complete the arguments of commands.

```
unset '_comps[bpython]'
```

Do this after the code that sets up completion (`compinit` and all that).